# Android Capture image and video in same time?

Tags: android

Android i have button "Capture image or Video",On Button click i want to either capture image or video.

But when  i call this intent ,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

its hide camera video record button,And if I call this intent,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
```

its start video recording no option for image capture ,What should i do? Any help?

Comment: No,I put button for each video and image ,,Some says that You have to work with Camera and you can create your own camera activity for both image and video ,,I think its so lengthy...so i put seperate button for each,,,

Comment: i also want something like this .can any one help?