# How to call one camera Intent having recording as well as image capture?

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

**Scenario:**

Start a camera intent where the intent should be able to record or capture image.

**What I already know:**

- To start camera intent for recording video

  `Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);`
- To start camera intent for capturing image

  `Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`

**Question:**
I have seen that whenever we start a camera as stand alone we get all the camera options like image capture,video recording,etc.

So,how may I create single intent having both the functionalities programatically ?

Note: I found same question on our forum([Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748491/android-capture-image-and-video-in-same-time)) but it was not answered,hence asking it again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This requires an answer :( Even I've to implement the same.